# Admob interstitial ads not closing. React native

Tags: react-native, admob, interstitial

We have an App that is made with react native and works perfectly for Android and iOS.

We include AdMob interstitial ads in the app and everything works fine with ads, using https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob

The problem is that with some interstitial ads (tests on IOs devices), mainly those that are interactive, they do not have the option to close (the interstitial) or the closed one does not work. And that means users get stuck in the ad, forcing the user to close the app.

We are using the latest version of the SDK. We have done a lot of research and have been unable to find a solution.

Any suggestion, please

real examples

[image][image]

Comment: Same issue here.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ios/FPCahTw4zaA

Comment: thank you for sharing, I think google already fixed the issue... the same ad that was giving me problems now is going well... ;)

Comment: I am seeing the same problem on stock Android.

Comment: did you solve. this issue.

Comment: Still error on mine  I am using    'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'